# Fundamental group of the union of subspaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $Y$ be a subspace that is a union of nested open subspaces of $X$: $Y=\bigcup Y_n$, where $Y_0\subset Y_1\subset\dots$. Suppose the smallest subspace (hence all subspaces) contains the base point $x_0$. Show that if the inclusions $Y_i\subset Y_{i+1}$ induce the trivial maps on the fundamental groups, then the fundamental group of $Y$ is trivial and that in the event that $\pi_1(Y,x_0)$ is trivial, some homomorphism $\pi_1(Y_0,x_0)\to\pi_1(Y_i,x_0)$ is trivial.

The first part seems to be clear. Namely, suppose each inclusion $\iota: Y_i\subset Y_{i+1}$ induces the trivial map. Let $f$ be a loop in $Y_i$ centered at $x_0$. Then $\iota \circ f$ is homotopic to the constant loop at $x_0$ in $Y_{i+1}$ by assumption. But the loop $f$ is equal to $\iota \circ f$ (and it lies in $Y_i$), so $f$ is homotopic to the constant loop at $x_0$ in $Y_i$; therefore, $\pi_1(Y_i,x_0)=\{1\}$  for all $i$. So if $g$ is any loop in $Y$, then $g$ is a loop in some $Y_i$ for $i$ sufficiently large, and thus is a trivial element of $\pi_1(Y_i,x_0)$ and hence of $\pi_1(Y,x_0).$ Is this proof correct?

For the second part, I'm not sure how to proceed. I have only trivial thoughts. Take $[f]\in \pi_1(Y,x_0)$. It is trivial. $f$ lies in $Y_i$ for $i$ large. But how to relate it to $Y_0$?.. I guess I can show that $\pi_1(Y_0,x_0)\to\pi_1(Y_i,x_0)$ is injective for that chosen $i$, but that's not what's being asked.

Comment: You didn't use the assumption about $Y_n$ being open. So take $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $Y=S^1$ and $Y_n$ to be a sequence of arcs such that the union is $Y$. Note that each $Y_n$ has trivial $\pi_1$ and hence inclusions induce trivial homomorphisms. But $\pi_1(Y)$ is not trivial. Note that this doesn't work if $Y_n$ are open in $Y$.

Comment: The particular mistake in your proof is "So if $g$ is any loop in $Y$, then $g$ is a loop in some $Y_i$ for $i$ sufficiently large". No, this is false. This is not true even up to homotopy. Take again the example of $S^1$ from my previous comment. Clearly the identity loop $S^1\to S^1$, $x\mapsto x$ is a counterxample.

Comment: So you fix that by assuming that each $Y_n$ is open. Then the image of $g$ (being compact) is covered by at most finitley many $Y_n$. And since $\{Y_n\}$ is a chain then the image is in $Y_m$ for some $m$.

Comment: Also the last statement is trivial? I mean $\pi_1$ is a functor and thus $\pi_1(Y_0)\to\pi_1(Y_i)$ is a composition of $\pi_1(Y_i)\to \pi_1(Y_{i+1})$ maps? Because composition of inclusions is an inclusion. Or is the "second part" without the assumption that homomorphisms induced from inclusions are trivial?

Comment: The second part without the assumption that inclusions induce trivial homomotphisms is not true. This time the counterexample is simplier, take $Z_n=\{n, n+1, n+2, \ldots\}$, $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $Y_n=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash (Z_n\times\{0\})$. The homotopy group of each $Y_n$ is an infinitely ranked free group and each inclusion induces a nontrivial, surjective (but not injective) homomorphism.

Comment: @freakish If we use compactness, then the image of $g$ indeed lies in $Y_m$, but we don't know that $Y_m$ has trivial fundamental group (as pointed out below, my proof of the fact that all $Y_i$ have trivial fundamental group is incorrect).

Comment: it doesn't matter what fundamental groups of $Y_n$ are. Since the inclusion induces trivial homomorphism then $g$ that has image in $Y_m$ has to be contractible in $Y_{m+1}$. This implies that the fundamental group of $Y$ is trivial.

Comment: Just remove the "therefore fundamental groups are trivial for all $i$" statement. It isn't true (I can show you an example if you wish). And what's more important: it's irrelevant. The correct statement is: "any loop $g$ in $Y$ is in $Y_m$ and thus it is contractible in $Y_{m+1}$ and thus in $Y$ as well. Therefore $Y$ has trivial fundamental group.".

Comment: @freakish I see, thanks. In your counterexample, is there an easy way to see that the inclusions cannot induce trivial homomorphisms?

Comment: The one I gave with $Z_n$? Yes, inducing a trivial homomorphism is equivalent to the fact that a given loop in $Y_n$ is contractible in $Y_{n+1}$. In my counterexample for a given $Y_n$ you take a loop around $(n+1,0)$, a small sphere. This loop is not contractible in neither $Y_n$ nor $Y_{n+1}$. In fact for any $m$ you can find such a loop in $Y_n$ that is not contractible in any $Y_m$: it's a sphere around $(m,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct : you cannot conclude that $\pi_1(Y_i, x_0)$ is trivial, because the homotopy taking $f$ to the constant loop may go outside $Y_i$.

But you don't need the triviality of this group to conclude afterwards.

And then later on you don't prove that $g$ is contained in some $Y_i$; you should at least mention in a few words why this is true.

The second part, however, is not true. Indeed, put $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$, and to describe the $Y_i$'s here's how they look : you take a strip like $(-1,1)\times (-1,\infty)$, and remove infinitely many points, specifically you remove $\{0\}\times\mathbb{N}$. That's your $Y_0$. Then $Y_i $, $i\geq 1$ is $Y_0$ together with the open ball of radius $i$ and centered at $0$.

Clearly the $Y_i$'s are open, they cover $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$, which has trivial fundamental group. However, $\pi_1(Y, 0)\to \pi_1(Y_i,0)$ is never the zero map.

To produce other counterexamples, try to think about how a supposed proof would go : you start from a loop $f$ in $Y_0$, it's homotopic to a constant loop in $Y$, the homotopy is entirely contained in a $Y_i$, so $f$ is sent to $0$ in $Y_i$. But wait, $i$ here depends on $f$ ! So to find a counterexample as I did, simply make the $i$ grow as $f$ changes : in my example this is what happens : the loops that go once around a missing point $(0,n)$ are homotopic to a constant map but not in $Y_n$.

Comment: But then how do I prove the first assertion? If I use the method suggested in the comments, then I cannot conclude that $g$ is the trivial loop in $Y_m$ because, as you pointed out, my proof proof that $\pi_1(Y_i,x_0)=\{1\}$ is wrong.

Comment: Of course but what about in $Y_{m+1}$ ?

Comment: But $f$ will be shrinkable in a $Y_j$ for $j$ large enough

Comment: Why will it be shrinkable in $Y_j$ for $j$ large? Are you using compactness somehow? By assumption $f$ is only shrinkable in $Y$, and the problem is to show it's shrinkable in $Y_0$. If it's shrinkable in $Y_j$, then I think I can apply successively that all the homomorphisms induced by "adjacent" inclusions are injective and conclude that $f$ is shrinkable in $Y_0$. But I don't see why $f$ is shrinkable in $Y_j$.

Comment: By compactness exactly, remember that the image of the homotopy $H: [0,1]\times [0,1]\to Y$ is compact

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how compactness is used. It only shows that $f$ lies in $Y_j$ for some $j$ (as in the original problem). But it's shrinkable only in $Y$ by assumption, and the homotopy may go outside $Y_j$.

Comment: The image of the homotopy $H: [0,1]\times [0,1]\to Y$ is contained in a $Y_j$ because $[0,1]^2$ is compact !!

Answer (score 1):

In order to add to what has been said, here's an example of $Y_n$ such that each $Y_n$ is open, each has a non-trivial fundamental group and each inclusion induces a trivial group homomorphism:

[image]

So in each step you fill the hole and you add another one to the right. And you go to infinity. I know that borders are thick but you should think about them as open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Each one of them is homotopically equivalent to $S^1$ and thus has $\mathbb{Z}$ as the fundamental group. Inclusions however induce trivial group homomorphism. This is equivalent to the fact that every loop in $Y_m$ is contractible in $Y_{m+1}$ (can you see why?).

Note that $Y$, which is equal to the union of all of them, is a contractible space.